# Code intelligence not working for Django komodo edit 10

Tags: django, python-3.x, komodo

I've been using komodo edit 10 for a while before I buy komodo ide to see if I like it or not, especially after I heard about all the features it offers. I use Django a lot for backend web development and one thing I noticed is code intelligence and auto completing doesn't seem to be working. I've been using Django 1.9.7 on Python 3.5.2 . I'm not sure what's happening, but any advice on fixing this issue is appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm using komodo edit version 10, and I'm running on OSX

Comment: I haven't updated to latest version of Komodo Edit yet, but in Komodo Edit version 9 on Windows 10 autocomplete works just fine. Try to mention your OS and version of Komodo Edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you've tried or whats not working (ie. what did you type and what did you expect to happen?) so I'll just explain how Komodo does it's thing:

When you open your Django project root in Komodo Places (*View > Tabs & Sidebars > Places*) Komodo should start scanning your project to include that code in Komodo's code intel database.  You may need to trigger a code intel event (**Ctrl + J** in the editor) to start the scan.  You'll see in the notifications (View > Tabs & Sidebars > Notifications) that Komodo is scanning your code.  While this is scanning you can continue to use Komodo but there will be no Code Intel suggestions at all.  When it has finished scanning you will get completions for the Python code Komodo found in your project.

*The above assumes you keep your Django code in your project root*.  If you don't, you must open *Preferences > Languages > Python | Python 3* (depending on whether you're using Python 2 or 3), scroll to **Additional Python Import Dirs** and add the location of your Django source, trigger a Completions event (same as above) and wait for scan to complete.

So, that's pretty much it.  If you're not getting ANY completions then you have to wait for Komodo to finish scanning.  If you're only missing Django completions you have to make sure Komodo knows about your Django source and where it's located.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and this is the output from notifications: http://imgur.com/a/TxCHR

I also tried your last suggestion and I'm not too sure which part of my django folder I need to go to. Is there a specific directory in my django project I need to direct komodo to?

Comment: re:image. The first notification says it's done scanning. Komodo is giving those warnings becuase there is no known symbol to complete on based on what you've typed.

Re: Django dirs.  Sorry, I have no idea. I don't do Django development.  I just work on the Komodo core code.  I watched this [video from one of our previous developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZP5T3ag118) and it looks like there should be **bin, include and lib** dirs in your project.  Those likely contains the Django specific code.

If it's still not working please provided an example of exactly what you're typing.